# Hint outcome of infinitely recursive type

Tags: typescript, recursion, types, infinite, hint

Given the following code:

```
type Recursive<A> = 
  | A
// We'd like to use `NeedsParsing<Recursive<A>>` here, but recursive types are only possible as "property values" (how are these correcly called?)
  | {
    parse: Recursive<A>;
  }

type NeedsParsing<A> = {
  parse: A;
}

type Parse<T> = T extends NeedsParsing<infer A>
  ? Parse<A>
  : T;

type X = Parse<Recursive<string>>;
//       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. (2589)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIB4CCAfFALxQBQUUAPlHhdVAN72VgCGaEAXLAihtnwEA3PQC+ZMqEhQAchAgATVAAUOGAHYBzISSb12nHnlESp4aGs44AKkVI2oEAB7AIG5XIXKrmneg0AMwhkWgJ6AH4oX1xCeh4bUXMZAA09GJw4JDQsXFRgZACtAhEyAHoyyigAPQigA)

In practice, `X` should resolve to `string`, since the infinitely deep type `Recursive<string>` can be resolved by the equally infinite recursive type `Parse<T>`.

However, this is something that TypeScript cannot deal with and errors rightfully with `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. (2589)`.

With [a depth limiter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIB4CCANFACIRjAAWUEAHsBAHYAmqUqwy6DA5lALxQARIIB8-AFBQoAHyh5JMqAApS5KrXrNWgqbr36hUAPxQGEbMigAuKAG8FUsAEM0EG3CRosuQlAAGACS2qpQAvv4iANwKoQCU4uKgkFAAchAQLAAKLhg8+GIC9o45bnLRoQlJ0NmuOAAqBVB11HSMLKnpWTlc3DhcAGYQlngiCiY1qD6jUjZ10Yng0AAa-FATuB4oGNg47Jw8IlHiAPTHugB6RkA), however, the type can be resolved again.

My question is not what the best way to go about my initial problem is. I am typing something that infinitely (ignore call stack) resolves types at runtime, and would like to represent this accurately with types without limiting myself to a certain recursion depth (16 in the above link).

Comment: "My question is not what the best way to go about my initial problem is." This confuses me.  What *is* your question? Is it that you want to know how to evaluate illegally circular types without a depth limiter? If so, I don't think that's possible. If not, then what?  And are you sure that `X` should be `string`?  What if I claimed it was `string | number`?  Or `string | Date`?  Or just `unknown`?   I'm pretty sure that none of those lead to a contradiction, so I'm not sure by what mechanism we can get the type you want without something like a depth cutoff.

Comment: `type Parse<T> = T extends Recursive<infer A> ? A : never;` [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIB4CCAfFALxR5QA+UA3lGAIZoQBcsCKG2+BA3FAL4AoQaEhQACo1S4AKkVIyoEAB7AIAOwAmqNkjRZc6dQDMIyMkQD8ZKK3URsyHsNHQAGiQlTccPZ1yowMhGAOYEvCLg7gCMnpJMOIHB6mGRYm4ATHHeOLQMTKx53oV0xVAARgD2lQA2EPTqAk38BGnuAMzZCYjqANbqlQDu6q0A9KNQGQAMUHXYNTqaEBBgbVBuACxd0rn50szUeyyHxScFZ-sXx0cHN1e3p3dPjy-nz2+vlzfqiAC25WZ+EDgSDQaDWkA)